# React JS Why does "value" not added by 1 but instead to "value1"?

Tags: reactjs

I am using *React Js* and I would like to increment value

My code as follow:

```
next() {
    console.log(this.state.myValue);
    if (this.state.myValue === this.state.Biggest) {
      alert('Biggest Number');
    } else {
      this.setState({ myValue: (this.state.myValue + 1) };
    }
  }

  prev() {
    if (this.state.myValue === this.state.Smallest) {
      alert('Smallest Number');
    } else {
      this.setState({ myValue: (this.state.myValue - 1) };
    }
  }

newmyValue(e) {
    this.setState({
      myValue: e.target.value,
    });
  }

<Input type="number" placeholder="eg 3" value={this.state.myValue} onChange={this.newmyValue} />
```

**Requirement**
`Smallest` from state is `1`
`Biggest` from state is `100`

The above result as expected should be `+1` and `-1` when calling `next` and `previous` function. What I faced is:

given `myValue` is `3`
the result from `next` is `31`
the result from `prev` is `2`
it seems like it just added `1` as string(?) instead if int

However, the above scenario continue
after first `next` is called `31`, I call `prev` is `30`
after first `prev` is called `2`, I call `next` is `3`

**Result:**

```
Input number: 3
(times)->  1  2    3    4      5      
next      31 311 3111 31111 311111
prev       3  2    1    1      1

Second try with next and prev cross calling
Input number: 3
       next    prev    next    prev      
case1    31      30      31      30 (goes 32 if call next)
       prev    next    prev    next
case2     2       3       2       3
```

What wrong with my coding?

Comment: Try `console.log(typeof e.target.value)` in `newmyValue` and you may get your answer.

Comment: It seems like your `e.target.value` is returning a `string`, try DrewReese suggestion and find out, if yes(is `string`) try `parseInt()`

Comment: Hi @DrewReese it is a string! and yes I try `parseInt()` and my code get working, but I wonder why the above scenario is happening to `-` but not for both situation?

Comment: String + <anything> is string concatenation where <anything> is coerced to string, but String - <anything> the string is attempted to be coerced to number and operated on. Try in console `"0" + 1`, then try `"0" - 1`. They will resolve to `"01"` and `-1` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this .

```
next() {
    console.log(this.state.myValue);
    if (this.state.myValue === this.state.Biggest) {
      alert('Biggest Number');
    } else {
      this.setState({ myValue: (parseInt(this.state.myValue) + 1) };
    }
  }

  prev() {
    if (this.state.myValue === this.state.Smallest) {
      alert('Smallest Number');
    } else {
      this.setState({ myValue: (parseInt(this.state.myValue) - 1) };
    }
  }

newmyValue(e) {
    this.setState({
      myValue: parseInt(e.target.value),
    });
  }
```

hope this'll help .

here is the reason why your code is not working

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_oper_concat5